# dynamic schedule based on units scheduled each day

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I have set up a jquery full calendar that can pull the units from a mysql script. Now my units available change daily based on scheduled employees / units. So each time the date is changed I need the units to update. Is this possible to do with fullcalendar?

I have tried this but does not seem to work.
calendar.php

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='../lib/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../lib/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<link href='../scheduler.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../lib/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='../scheduler.min.js'></script>
<script>

  $(function() { // document ready

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      defaultView: 'agendaDay',

      editable: true,
      selectable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaDay,agendaTwoDay,agendaWeek,month'
      },
      views: {
        agendaTwoDay: {
          type: 'agenda',
          duration: { days: 2 },

          // views that are more than a day will NOT do this behavior by default
          // so, we need to explicitly enable it
          groupByResource: true

          //// uncomment this line to group by day FIRST with resources underneath
          //groupByDateAndResource: true
        }
      },

      //// uncomment this line to hide the all-day slot
      //allDaySlot: false,






refetchResourcesOnNavigate: true,
resources: function(callback, start, end, timezone) {


  $.ajax({
   url:"units.php",
   type:"POST",
   data:{ 
     start: start.format(),
     end: end.format(),
     timezone: timezone
   },
   success: function(resourceObjects) //define a variable to capture the JSON from the server
   {
     callback(resourceObjects); //return the new resource data to the calendar
   }
})},




      events: 'load.php',

select: function(start, end, allDay)
    {
     var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
     if(title)
     {
      var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      $.ajax({
       url:"insert.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{title:title, start:start, end:end},
       success:function()
       {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        alert("Added Successfully");
       }
      })
     }
    },
    editable:true,
    eventResize:function(event)
    {
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var id = event.id;
     var resourceId = event.resourceId;
     $.ajax({
      url:"update.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id, resourceId:resourceId},
      success:function(){
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       alert('Event Update');
      }
     })
    },

    eventDrop:function(event)
    {
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var id = event.id;
     var resourceId = event.resourceId;
     $.ajax({
      url:"update.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id, resourceId:resourceId},
      success:function()
      {
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       alert("Event Updated");
      }
     });
    },

    eventClick:function(event)
    {
     if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?"))
     {
      var id = event.id;
      $.ajax({
       url:"delete.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{id:id},
       success:function()
       {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        alert("Event Removed");
       }
      })
     }
    },

   });
  });

</script>
<style>

  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  #calendar {
    max-width: 99%;
    margin: 50px auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

units.php

```
<?php

//load.php
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$tz = $_POST['timezone'];

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=', '', 'pass');

$data = array();

$query = "select s.*, u.unit_number from schedules s
          left join units u on u.id = s.unit where s.start_time like '$start%'";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    /* Get Shift Start and calculate end time
      $start = date('G:i', $row['start_time']);
      $shift_lentgth = $row[''];
      $end= strtotime("+ $shift_lentgth", $start);
     */

    // Check unit level to give identifier

    $data[] = array(
        'id' => $row["id"],
        'title' => $row["unit_number"]
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code really makes very little sense. The main problem is that you've defined the "resources" option twice, and I've no idea what the one with the functions attached to it is trying to do. In the worst case it would probably cause an infinite loop of refetching. Luckily it gets overridden by the static reference to "units.php" later in your options list, and so never gets used.

It looks like you're trying to set the resource list based on the currently selected date range, which is perfectly reasonable and possible, but you seem to have got a bit confused and thus your code is not logical.

Firstly, remove:

```
resources: "units.php"
```

entirely, since this overwrites your attempt to dynamically control the resources.

Secondly, you can set the following:

```
refetchResourcesOnNavigate: true,
resources: function(callback, start, end, timezone) {
  $.ajax({
   url:"units.php",
   type:"POST",
   data:{ 
     "start": start.format(),
     "end": end.format(),
     "timezone": timezone,
   },
   success: function(resourceData) //define a variable to capture the JSON from the server
   {
     callback(resourceData); //return the new resource data to the calendar
   }
}
```

**Notes:**

- See that I have changed the data sent to your ajax call to cover a *range* of time instead of a single date - based on the views you've made available via your header options, it's perfectly possible for the calendar to be showing a day, 2 days, a week, or a month in one display. So your server needs to be able to return all resources which are relevant to any of the days within the range. I've also included the timezone variable in case you need that in your scenario.
- "refetchResourcesOnNavigate" - as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/refetchResourcesOnNavigate this causes the resources to be refetched automatically whenever the date range is changed by the user, and also causes any "resources" custom callback function to be given the current date range and timezone as parameters which can be forwarded on to the server.
- resources as a function: this should simply make a call to the server and return the results, passing on the currently selected date range so that the server can return the correct results. Calling "refetchResources" within it, as you did in your version, makes no sense since this will simply result in the same function being called again and cause an infinite loop - this callback function *is* the process by which the resources are refetched. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-function for more.

Comment: I have updated code with your suggestions. After taking out the resources: ['units.php'],    line and inserting your example. I get a blank screen. I followed your links above to the docs and noticed they used resourceObjects instead of resourcedata, this also did not work. I will keep making stabs at it. I am sorry about my code not making sense I am very new to js and fullcalendar

Comment: Made another change and updated code above now I can get the navigation to display however now calendar.

Comment: "noticed they used resourceObjects instead of resourcedata"...you can name your callback parameters "sjgdfjkghrkgw" if you like, it makes no difference to how they work or what they contain, the name is only to help the developer, same as any other variable. So that's not the problem. Since you mention getting a blank calendar, have you checked your browser's Console for errors to ensure you haven't made a syntax error or caused some other problem? Have you also verified that units.php actually returns JSON in the correct format? Please add that JSON to the question if you're unsure.

Answer (score -1):

Utilize

```
refetchResourcesOnNavigate: true,
  resources: '/my-resource-script.php'
```

more info at [fullcalendar docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-json-feed)